# UTF8 Output Issue Laravel PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

Me and character and encoding have never gotten along, and I wonder if someone could assist with a problem I'm struggling with. It's mostly likely an encoding 101 issue, although having scoured documents, forums, etc, I cannot find a solution.

My environment:

Laravel 5.5 on XAMMP (Windows)

My database has names such as:
"D\xc3\xacaz de la Pe\xc3\xb1a"

Which would and should output as "Díaz de la Peña"

According to the UT8 charts, these characters are correct:
http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&names=-&utf8=string-literal

Was a mistake made in saving to the database in that format? Should they have been encoded in some other way?

Or am I just not outputting it right. I've tried utf8_encode and utf8_decode and the only output I ever seem to get is the same "D\xc3\xacaz de la Pe\xc3\xb1a"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to replace `\xXX` values, using [`hexdec()`](https://php.net/hexdec) and [`chr()`](https://php.net/chr):

```
$str = 'D\xc3\xacaz de la Pe\xc3\xb1a' ;
$str = preg_replace_callback('~\\\\x([a-f0-9]{2})~', function($match) {
    return chr(hexdec($match[1]));
}, $str);
echo $str ;
```

Outputs :

```
"Dìaz de la Peña"
```

The code above takes all strings that match with `\x` followed by 2 hexadecimal characters. Then, they are converted into decimal value using `hexdec()`, and finally converted to a character using `chr()`.

You also could replace `[a-f0-9]` to `[[:xdigit:]]`:

```
'~\\\\x([[:xdigit:]]{2})~'
```

Here is the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uUzesG/1) of the matches.

Comment: Thanks the first example works great, I made a function out of it. Am I wrong for storing those UTF8 characters in the database in those codesets? Is there another way your supposed to do it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe you could store the string with encoded characters directly instead of encode them each time you need them. But I don't know how you are storing them and how your database is configured. Also, don't forget to close your question if an answer solves your problem. Thanks :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235